# Rails | Process json return in js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a `:remote => true` which works as expected. I am having a trouble with the js return.

```
def myfunc
...
    respond_to do |format|
                if !response.nil?
                    r = response.to_hash
                    format.js { render :json => {:IsLoggedIn => true, :response => r }}
                    format.html
                else
                    @error = "Try again"
                    format.js { render :json => {:IsLoggedIn => false, :response => @error }}
                    format.html
                end
             end

end
```

Then in `myfunc.js.erb` how can I get `IsLoggedIn` & `response` values?

Answer (score 0):

As per your case , you are using this function only for js . So write it like below:

```
def myfunc
...
  @r = response
end
```

In your `myfunc.js.erb` , write the below:

```
<% if @r.present? %>
  {:IsLoggedIn => true, :response => @r }
<% else %>
  {:IsLoggedIn => true, :response => "Try Again" }
<% end %>

@r is available in js.erb , so you set it your html div like $("#yourdivid").val("<%= @r.id" %>")
```